# In this table structure, how to search for articles by field values?

Tags: mysql, sql

Among the joomla tables there are these three tables, **content** that stores the articles, **fields** that stores the definition of custom fields and **fields_values** that stores the values assigned to these custom fields in articles.

Here the table definitions with some of their fields

```
content
-------------
  id
  title

fields
-------------
  id
  title
  name

fields_values
-------------
  field_id <-- field_id refer to content id
  item_id
  value
```

I need to search content records for the values in field_values, but I don't know how to do it

For convenience I created this [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26e0cb)

The [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa4318) with the value target

Given the sqlfiddle sample data I need to search for the articles (content records) where any of the fields have the value `target`

The expected results would be the article with id 1 because in `field1` of article 1 has the value `target` and the article with id 3 because in `field2` of article 3 has the value `target`

I appreciate your advice...

Comment: None of the `fields_values.value` values in your sqlfiddle contain the word `target`

Comment: And what is `item_id` supposed to refer to?

Comment: item_id refer to content id, I will update the question

Comment: I should have shared the sqlfiddle before modifying the value per target, I assumed a change would be reflected in the link, I updated the question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join `fields` table to `fields_values` table using `field_id` and join this joint table to content using `fields_values.item_id`.

Then in where clause you can give values for `fields.title` and `field_values.value` to get columns from content table.

There will be duplicates from content table. So you can select with distinct or you can group by in content table:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.title FROM fields f 
  join fields_values v on f.id=v.field_id 
  join content c on c.id=v.item_id
  WHERE f.title='{field_title}' and v.value='{value}'
```

> Although not a part of question. Without proper indexing this schema will not scale very well with big data. I suggest to optimize indexing on all tables, especially index columns.

Comment: Thank you for answering, the query you share works as expected, following the example shown and with the requirement that I need to search for each field this is the query I am using `SELECT DISTINCT c.id, c.title FROM fields f 
  join fields_values v on f.id=v.field_id 
  join content c on c.id=v.item_id
  WHERE (f.title='field1' and v.value='{value}') or (f.title='field2' and v.value = '{value}')`

Comment: This answer was mentioned in [joomla.se] Stack Exchange [here](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/q/26341/12352)